# Is the 'Sell It' button annoying?

Tags: mobile, buttons, android, lists

[image]

I am developing an android application that is about buying or selling second hand stuff around your area. The screenshot is from the list of the app and i wonder if this button will be annoying for the users and if i should just remove it.

Comment: What is it the user sells from the list? What does the sell it button do?

Comment: The sell it button navigates the user to a new page where he can create a new classified

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming this is a Direct Primary Action similar to **Instagram's New Photo** button.

Is it annoying? **No.**

Is it confusing? **Hell yes.**

Reasons that it is confusing:

1. The button is floating. If you want to have a Floating Action Button, you could use the Android Design Support Library and use the FAB itself without any text needed.
2. On Android, it looks like a Toast message with a custom background.
3. I'm considering the button isn't fixed and hides itself when user scrolls. This provokes the user each time they scroll up to click on the button since it reveals itself.
4. There isn't any context as to what you mean by "*Sell it*". On a page of browsing buying options, a button called Sell it is present.

Solutions:

1. Remove the *Sell* button from any Offers page where the User is looking to *Buy*.
2. Use [Bottom Navigation](https://material.google.com/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-usage) to specify two activities + other activities (upto 5): Buying and Selling which the User can switch simultaneously without losing the state of the previous activity.

I personally recommend the 2nd option since Buyers and Sellers know what these terms mean. Also, it's easier to know comprehend what each page does. If the user is a buyer, he need not be provoked to sell anything.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, i might go with the floating button, its something that a lot of applications do

Comment: No problem, Akis! It's a good solution, but I would recommend using a Plus FAB instead of a direct Sell one.

Comment: Yes exactly! It will be a fab with the camera icon.

Answer (score 1):

It's both annoying and confusing:

- Annoying because it's covering the images.
- Confusing because it is out of context. You're on a page where you are looking for offers nearby, there's no reason to include a Sell It button.

I recommend you look at this app called [Saily](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/saily/id846198889?ls=1&mt=8) for benchmarking.
The option for "Buy it" or "Sell it" shouldn't be available on the interface were you list items. You probably have to add other details here like price or location and the Call to action should be available in the Item page screen.